# Secondary Leadership boost vs primary leadership

Tags: royal-revolt-2

In Royal Revolt 2, how does the "Leadership boost" work ?

I have item #1 that gives me primary leadership of 1005 and secondary leadership boost of 103.4

Then again, I have item #2 which gives me primary leadership of 1253 and no secondary boosts.

Doing the math, item #2 gives more leadership since 1005+103.4=1108.4 < 1253

But then again, I see that the selling price of item #1 is more than that of #2 (#1 has 92793 gold selling price and #2 has 30696 gold selling price).

I'm not sure how this works. Can someone explain me this ?

[image: Item1]

[image: Item 2]

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, leadership affects your starting morale and recharge rate. The wiki is unclear on what the leadership boost does, but I found a [video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OkXpqhgiLBA/) saying that the leadership boost only affects the recharge rate.

Answer (score 0):

Leadership boost is just additional leadership on your item.  On capes and helmets, you can just add it to the base leadership.

They numbers aren't merged because it's a bonus, and leadership bonus can be found on other items such as boots and rings.

---

**Example:**

*Kingly Master Helmet:*
2007 base leadership.
998 leadership bonus.

Total leadership = 2007 + 998 = 3005.

---

The reason why the cape with lower total leadership has a higher value is that it is a rare (blue) quality item which is better than an enchanted (green).

Another reason is that it has a bonus.  My sword deals ~110 dmg with ~65 ice dmg.  But my other sword with ~100 dmg with 75 ice dmg is worth 70 000 more.